# Visual Basic - Select Dropdownlists option

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, browser, controls

Im filling in a site with Webbrowser control, the problem is the site contains two dropdownlists and they are linked to each other like

```
<select name="dropdown1" id="dropdown1">
<option value="1"test1</option>
<option value="2"test2</option>
</select>
<select....>
<option value="">&nbsp;</option>
</select>
```

If i use

```
Webbrowser1.document.getelementbyid("dropdown1").setattribute("Value", "1")
```

it does select the value 1 of dropdownlist1 but it doesnt activate dropdownlist 2 with options that belong to the choice on the first dropdownlist

The only way i get it working is to select it with the mouse and click on my option but i want it to be automatic. I hope i have informed you well enough.

Comment: the second dropdownlist dosnt got any id? or name? i guess it got a name like dropdown2. so u only need to add the same code just with the other id.  Webbrowser1.document.getelementbyid("dropdown2").setattribute("Value", "1")

Comment: @samy yes the second dropdownlist also has an id like dropdown2 but there are only options in that list if the 1rst one is clicked and i cant do that automatic. If you use the code you told me it wont function becuase there is no value1

Comment: this is a guess! you said this work only if u click the first dropdownlist. so you can invoke the click method like this: `Webbrowser1.document.getelementbyid("dropdown1").InvokeMember("click");` or instad of that try `Webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dropdown1").Focus();`

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer wasnt totally right but it gave me the good direction. Now i have (WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dropdown1").SetAttribute("Value", "1")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dropdown1").Focus()
        SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}")
        SendKeys.Send("{Up}") and it works :D

Answer (score 0):

The `Webbrowser` is WPF is notoriously poor, and the interaction with it isn't any better.  If you can avoid using it, I highly suggest avoiding it.

When I do have to muck with it, I normally do all my interactions through JavaScript.  I'll set up a JavaScript function on the page being served by the `Webbrowser` and call it from the WPF code.  This way all the DOM interaction is being done by the web page itself.

In this scenario you would have HTML resembling:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectOption(param)
        {
            if (param == "value3") {
                var combo1 = document.getElementById("dropdown1");
                combo1.value = 3;
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select name="dropdown1" id="dropdown1">
            <option value="1">test 1</option>
            <option value="2">test 2</option>
            <option value="3">test 3</option>
        </select>
        <select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2">
            <option value="a">test a</option>
            <option value="b">test b</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowWorkbench.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Content="Click Me!" />
        <WebBrowser Name="MyBrowser" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

XAML.CS:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyBrowser.Navigate(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/HTMLPage1.html");
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyBrowser.InvokeScript("selectOption", new String[] { "value3" });
    }
}
```

The example code still doesn't change the second drop down, but because you are now interacting with the DOM directly from the JavaScript you can easily access it.  You could extend the `selectOption` function to access it directly, for example.

Comment: Thank you so much for tanking the time to answer my question but this method is kind of new for me and im quite well in html but not that good with java and C# so how can i use this in my visual basic form? Edit: The site I want to fill in isn't mine

Comment: Ah... working with a HTML site you can't edit doesn't allow you to use this method.  I'll have to look into it more.